# What is ^X in in Linux?

Tags: c, character, output, cat

For my homework assignment, I have to make sure that my output matches the solution output 100% or I don't get credit.

My output is:

> hw05-data-10.txt  : min =   5, max =  90, mean =  51.23, variance =   618.34

The solution output is:

> hw05-data-10.txt  : min =   5, max =  90, mean =  51.23, variance =   618.34

They look similar, however when I use diff mine.txt solution.txt, I get a difference.

I used `cat -tev mine.txt` and `cat -tev solution.txt` to find the difference, and I found that mine looks like:

> hw05-data-10.txt^X  : min =   5, max =  90, mean =  51.23, variance =   618.34$

and the solution looks like:

> hw05-data-10.txt  : min =   5, max =  90, mean =  51.23, variance =   618.34$

What is `^X`? I've tried looking around but I can't find the answer. How can I remove this from my output? It's a C program.

Comment: Not having seen your C program, or how it generates (reformats input data?) no one will be able to tell you how to fix it.

Comment: Since the problem is caused by a C program, this would be better if it was edited to be a C programming question rather than an OS question (don't forget to update the tags).

Answer (score 1):

`^X` is the <kbd>CTRL-X</kbd> character, made visible by the `-v` flag of `cat`.

If you want to get rid of it, you can pass the contents through something like:

```
tr -d '[:cntrl:]'
```

See the following transcript for an example (the `^X` is inserted in `bash` with <kbd>CTRL-V</kbd><kbd>CTRL-X</kbd>):

```
pax> echo '123^X456' | cat -v
123^X456

pax> echo '123^X456' | tr -d '[:cntrl:]' | cat -v
123456
```

If you want to remove it at the *source* rather than filtering after the event, you need to investigate the program that's creating your `mine.txt` file. It will be the one inserting the rogue character.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to check why the program that created the output wrote the control character and get rid of it at the source?

Answer (score 0):

According to the man page of `cat` command,

> **-v** flag:  Display non-printing characters so they are visible.  Control characters print as `^X` for control-X; the delete character (octal 0177) prints as `^?`.  Non-ASCII characters (with the high bit set) are printed as `M-` (for meta) followed by the character for the low 7 bits
>
> **-e** flag: Display non-printing characters (see the -v option), and display a dollar sign (`$') at the end of each line.

Therefore, the answer of `^X` is a [Control Character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character). To remove from output, remove the `-v` and `-e` flag from your `cat` command if possible. If can't, you have to investigate your C program: why it's generating this control character.

Comment: Even when removing the -v flag, it still prints the same output with the ^X.

After running the program, it doesn't show the ^X, and even when I use cat mine.txt, it still doesn't show the ^X. However, when I open mine.txt in vim, it shows the ^X. I'm so confused.

Comment: Further look into the man page, `-e` flag also instructs the `cat` command to display non-printing characters. Use command `man cat` to learn more.

Comment: most likely (with seeing the actual code) there is some trash in the output buffer, probably in the field with the file name.  pre setting the fields to all '\0' will eliminate the trash.

Comment: @Hazim, the `^X` is generated **by your C program**.  You have to look at the source code of that program to see why it is generating it in the output.  You have not posted your code, so no more help can be given.  **-v** option of **cat(1)** is only *to see* (to diagnose the problem, *not to repair*) what the difference is, between your output and teacher's one.  You have **to edit your source file and erase that control character from the output routines you are calling**.

Answer (score 0):

`^X` is ASCII CAN, cancel control character.  Normally it is not used by the linux tty driver on output, so you will not see it when output to the terminal.  If you use it on input, linux tty driver will interpret it as the `STOP` character and will send a `SIGSTOP` signal to the foreground process, causing it to stop execution until it receives a `SIGSTART` signal.  The character you mention is probably somewhat inserted in the format string you used for the **printf(3)** call. (you have not shown your code snippet in the question)

The `^X` character is also used in some window environments to Cut the selected text, so probably you inserted it at some undesired place in the program source code.